# Spring Boot Quartz : Can quartz schedule a job at runtime for every nodes (clustered mode)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, quartz-scheduler

I am creating a scheduler mechanism for a micro service architectured java spring boot project. I'm  using quartz with clustered mode on. I have configured the schedulerFactory bean, jobFactory bean and triggerFactory bean for spring so i can inject them with spring. Thus, spring creates all factory beans for me at startup. And since quartz uses those factory beans ( to create beans ), there will be 6 beans in my contexts (for each node) : schedulerFactoryBean, schedulerBean, jobFactoryBean, jobBean, triggerFactoryBean and factoryBean at the startup on each node.

I can inject these beans into controller and manipulate them as a like , i can even create new scheduler, job and triggers.

As i know, quartz only keeps the factory beans synced through database.( at the start up , each nodes creates a record at the related table that says, " hey i am here" ).

Here's my question. When i want to create a scheduler bean through a rest endpoint , i have to send the same request to every node. What i want quartz to do is : i want to send only one request to only one node and the other nodes should sync their selfs (Since i have a clustered struchture, the receiver node will be random).

My second question is :
 since beans are kept in heap, at every start up, my runtime created objects gets flushed. I want them to be persistant. Can quartz do that ? Is there anyway i can do this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `First question`: you should create a multi-thread handler to execute jobs sync.
`Second question`: I am not sure why would you like to having beans that are persisted?

Comment: I did't get what you're refering to. Where should i use multi-thread handler ?

Comment: you can several listeners to trigger some job then you might have a multi-thread handler so that each job is executed based on your logic.

Comment: i dont think you understand the problem. Problem is not running jobs sync. I already have that. My problem is does quartz syncs the beans created at runtime on a clustered mode ( not the jobs )